# Where are users stored when using v2.0 common endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

If I register an app in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ it works as intended. I can modify the endpoint to use a specific AD tenant, or to just use "common" *(Allows users with both personal Microsoft accounts and work/school accounts from Azure Active Directory to sign into the application.)*

My question is, when using common, i.e `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/...`

Where do new users get stored? I want people to be able to sign in/create accounts using any Microsoft account (common), but where are they stored when I use this endpoint? How do I administer them and/or my application as I would a normal AAD Tenant with an application registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, when using common, i.e https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/...
>
> Where do new users get stored? I want people to be able to sign in/create accounts using any Microsoft account (common), but where are they stored when I use this endpoint? How do I administer them and/or my application as I would a normal AAD Tenant with an application registration?

The [Azure AD v2.0 endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-compare#microsoft-accounts-and-azure-ad-accounts) supports both Microsoft Accounts and Azure AD accounts.

The [Microsoft Account](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/account) provides a single sign-in to access all of your Microsoft services – from Office to Outlook to Skype. It store and manage by Microsoft, we are not able to manage the Microsoft Accounts.

If the users sign-in the app using Azure AD account. The admin of that tenant can manage them as usual.